# Ejecutar varios metodos dentro de AsyncSatck

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Estoy desarrollando una app para android, la cual me manda un webervices y lo consumiendo por kSoap, ya estoy en el proceso final de la app, estoy en la parte de grabado, en la cual cuando el usuario le de TAP en la opción guardar esta tiene que hacer un proceso en segundo en la cual se tiene que hacer un llamado al webservices para mandar la información recolectada y  guardarla en el sistema.

El detalle es que bueno para grabar primero tengo que mandar a llamar un metodo que se llama obtenerrecurso el cual este me da id, tengo otro metodo que tengo llamar que se llama LlenarEncabezado y otro mas de LlenarDetalle, mi duda o donde estoy atorado, es saber si puedo hacer un segundo llamado dentro de un mismo Asynstack... por ejemplo que cuando haga el llamdo de obtenerrecuso y que ese id se me guarde y que en ese mismo hilo pueda llamar al webservices al mi segundo metdo que seria LlenarEncarbezado, no se si me puedan explicar como hacerlo, les dejo mi codigo

Metodos webservices

ObtenerRecurso

```
 public static int ObtenerRecurso()
    {

        // Create request
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9020/","ObtenerRecurso");
        // Property which holds input parameters

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes=false;
        // Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        // Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,7000);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            // Invoke web service
            androidHttpTransport.call("http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9020/ObtenerRecurso", envelope);
            String ss = androidHttpTransport.responseDump;
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            //Assign Error Status true in static variable 'errored'
            //menu.errored = true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return Integer.parseInt(null);
    }
```

Metodo LlenarEncabezado

```
 public static void LLenarEncabezadoCXCP(int Recurso,
                                            String Accion,
                                            int Id,
                                            int Empresa,
                                            String Folio,
                                            Date Fecha,
                                            int Cliente,
                                            int Proveedor,
                                            int Moneda,
                                            double TipoCambio,
                                            int BancoCuenta,
                                            String UsuarioCaptura,
                                            int PagoForma,
                                            double Saldo,
                                            double Importe,
                                            double Financiamiento,
                                            double Descuento,
                                            double SubTotal,
                                            double Retencion1,
                                            double Retencion2,
                                            double IEPS,
                                            double IVA,
                                            double ISH,
                                            double Total,
                                            double TotalAplicado,
                                            String Status,
                                            String UsuarioCancela,
                                            double Numero1,
                                            double Numero2,
                                            double Numero3,
                                            double Numero4,
                                            double Numero5,
                                            double Numero6,
                                            double Numero7,
                                            double Numero8,
                                            double Numero9,
                                            double Numero10,
                                            String Texto1,
                                            String Texto2,
                                            String Texto3,
                                            String Texto4,
                                            String Texto5,
                                            String Texto6,
                                            String Texto7,
                                            String Texto8,
                                            String Texto9,
                                            String Texto10,
                                            Date Fecha1,
                                            Date Fecha2,
                                            Date Fecha3,
                                            Date Fecha4,
                                            Date Fecha5,
                                            Date Fecha6,
                                            String Observaciones,
                                            int Concepto,
                                            String ObservacionCancelacion,
                                            int OrigenVentaCompra,
                                            int OrigenInventario)
    {
        // Create request
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9020/","LLenarEncabezadoCXCP");
        request.addProperty("Recurso",Recurso);
        request.addProperty("Accion"," ");
        request.addProperty("Id", "");
        request.addProperty("Empresa","");
        request.addProperty("Folio", "");
        request.addProperty("Fecha"," ");
        request.addProperty("Cliente"," ");
        request.addProperty("Proveedor","");
        request.addProperty("Moneda"," ");
        request.addProperty("TipoCambio"," ");
        request.addProperty("BancoCuenta"," ");
        request.addProperty("UsuaurioCaptura","");
        request.addProperty("PagoForma","");
        request.addProperty("Saldo","");
        request.addProperty("Importe","");
        request.addProperty("Financiamiento","");
        request.addProperty("Descuento","");
        request.addProperty("SubTotal","");
        request.addProperty("Retencion2","");
        request.addProperty("Retencion2","");
        request.addProperty("IEPS","");
        request.addProperty("IVA","");
        request.addProperty("ISH","");
        request.addProperty("Total","");
        request.addProperty("TotalAplicado","");
        request.addProperty("Status","");
        request.addProperty("UsuarioCancela","");
        request.addProperty("Numero1","");
        request.addProperty("Numero2","");
        request.addProperty("Numero3","");
        request.addProperty("Numero4","");
        request.addProperty("Numero5","");
        request.addProperty("Numero6","");
        request.addProperty("Numero7","");
        request.addProperty("Numero8","");
        request.addProperty("Numero9","");
        request.addProperty("Numero10","");
        request.addProperty("Texto1","");
        request.addProperty("Texto2","");
        request.addProperty("Texto3","");
        request.addProperty("Texto4","");
        request.addProperty("Texto5","");
        request.addProperty("Texto6","");
        request.addProperty("Texto7","");
        request.addProperty("Texto8","");
        request.addProperty("Texto9","");
        request.addProperty("Texto10","");
        request.addProperty("Fecha1","");
        request.addProperty("Fecha2","");
        request.addProperty("Fecha3","");
        request.addProperty("Fecha4","");
        request.addProperty("Fecha5","");
        request.addProperty("Fecha6","");
        request.addProperty("Observacion","");
        request.addProperty("Catalogo1","");
        request.addProperty("Catalogo2","");
        request.addProperty("Catalogo3","");
        request.addProperty("Catalogo4","");
        request.addProperty("Catalogo5","");
        request.addProperty("Catalogo6","");
        request.addProperty("OrdenCompra","");
        request.addProperty("Concepto","");
        request.addProperty("ObservacionCancelacion","");
        request.addProperty("OrigenVentaCompra","");
        request.addProperty("OrigenInventario","");


        // Property which holds input parameters

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes=false;
        // Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        // Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,7000);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            // Invoke web service
            androidHttpTransport.call("http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9020/LLenarEncabezadoCXCP", envelope);
            String ss = androidHttpTransport.responseDump;
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

        } catch (SoapFault soapFault) {
            soapFault.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return;
    }
```

Metodo Llenar detalle

```
    public static String LLenarDetalleCXCP(int Recurso,
                                                String Accion,
                                                int Id,
                                                int Origen,
                                                int OrigenDocumento,
                                                double Importe,
                                                double Financiamiento,
                                                double Descuento,
                                                double SubTotal,
                                                double Retencion1,
                                                double Retencion2,
                                                double IEPS,
                                                double IVA,
                                                double ISH,
                                                double Total,
                                                double Saldo,
                                                String Referencia)
         {

             SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9020/","ObtenerRecurso");
             request.addProperty("Recurso","");
             request.addProperty("Accion","");
             request.addProperty("Id","");
             request.addProperty("Origen","");
             request.addProperty("OrigenDocumento","");
             request.addProperty("Importe","");
             request.addProperty("Financiamiento","");
             request.addProperty("Descuento","");
             request.addProperty("SubTotal","");
             request.addProperty("Retencion1","");
             request.addProperty("Retencion2","");
             request.addProperty("IEPS","");
             request.addProperty("IVA","");
             request.addProperty("ISH","");
             request.addProperty("Total","");
             request.addProperty("Saldo","");
             request.addProperty("Referencia","");
             // Property which holds input parameters

             SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
             envelope.dotNet = true;
             envelope.implicitTypes=false;
             // Set output SOAP object
             envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
             // Create HTTP call object
             HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,7000);

             try {
                 androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
                 // Invoke web service
                 androidHttpTransport.call("http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9020/LLenarEncabezadoCXCP", envelope);
                 String ss = androidHttpTransport.responseDump;
                 SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

             } catch (SoapFault soapFault) {
                 soapFault.printStackTrace();
             } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

             String resultado = null;
             return resultado ;
         }
```

código botón

```
         Button pagar = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnpago);
                pagar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {

                        AsyncGrabarCXCP task = new AsyncGrabarCXCP();
                        //Call execute
                        task.execute();
        }

});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

clase asyn para grabar

public class AsyncGrabarCXCP extends AsyncTask
    {
        int Recurso;

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog=new ProgressDialog(Detalle_Cliente.this);
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setMessage("Guardando Datos...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Recurso=webService.ObtenerRecurso();
        Recurso=webService.LLenarEncabezadoCXCP(recurso,accion,id,empresa,folio,fecha,cliente,proveedor,moneda,tipoCambio,bancocuenta,
                                                usuariocaptura,pagoforma,saldo,importe,financiamiento,descuento,subtotal,retencion1,retencion2,
                                                ieps,iva,ish,total,totalaplicado,status,usucariocancela,numero1,numero2,numero3,numero4,numero5,
                                                numero6,numero7,numero8,numero9,numero10,texto1,texto2,texto3,texto4,texto5,texto6,texto7,
                                                texto8,texto9,texto10,fecha1,fecha2,fecha3,fecha4,fecha5,fecha6,observaciones,concepto,observacioncancelacion,
                                                origeninventario,origeninventario);
        Recurso=webService.LLenarDetalleCXCP(_recurso,accion,id,origen,origendocumento,importe,financiamiento,descuento,subtotal,retencion1,retencion2,ieps,
                                              iva,ish,total,saldo,refencia);
        return Integer.valueOf("");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
        super.onPostExecute(integer);
    }
}
```

El stacktrace de logcat

```
errro Logcat

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
                                                                                  Process: mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile, PID: 23061
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                                                                                      at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
                                                                                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                                                                                      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
                                                                                      at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:489)
                                                                                      at mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile.Detalle_Cliente$AsyncGrabarCXCP.doInBackground(Detalle_Cliente.java:224)
                                                                                      at mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile.Detalle_Cliente$AsyncGrabarCXCP.doInBackground(Detalle_Cliente.java:199)
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 
05-09 19:41:30.417 23061-23061/mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile.Detalle_Cliente has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{52ac37e4 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
                                                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:346)
                                                                                     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
                                                                                     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
                                                                                     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
                                                                                     at mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile.Detalle_Cliente$AsyncGrabarCXCP.onPreExecute(Detalle_Cliente.java:210)
                                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
                                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
                                                                                     at mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile.Detalle_Cliente$1.onClick(Detalle_Cliente.java:77)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de crear varios `AsyncTask`, dentro de tu `AsyncTask`

```
 AsyncGrabarCXCP task = new AsyncGrabarCXCP();
            //Call execute
            task.execute();
```

puedes agregar los 3 métodos para que se ejecuten secuencialmente:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    ObtenerRecurso();
   LLenarEncabezadoCXCP();
   LLenarDetalleCXCP();
    return "";
}
```

Veo que tu método `LLenarDetalleCXCP()`, no realiza modificaciones a la UI, si agregas ese código posteriormente, recuerda que las operaciones para modificar tu UI la puedes realizar dentro de `onPostExecute()`,

#### -------------------Actualización-------------------------------------------------------

Por eso preguntaba si tus métodos funcionaban sin problema porque si no es así van a  salir otro tipo de problemas que no tiene nada que que ver con la pregunta, por ejemplo el error que tienes:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive cannot be cast to
>   org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject

Es porque estas recibiendo un String , por lo tanto esto es incorrecto:

```
 SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
```

tiene que ser:

```
SoapPrimitive response =  (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
```

Te recomiendo pruebes primero todos los métodos por separado para asegurar su correcto funcionamiento.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41542/discussion-on-answer-by-elenasys-ejecutar-varios-metodos-dentro-de-asyncsatck).